# Adding and deleting inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to add rows to a formulary that has already been generated dynamically.

Here is what I try to do:

First I generate the view:

```
 @foreach($items as $item)
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item[]" value="{{$item->name}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm" id="deleteitem">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                        </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" id="addrow"></div>
                    @endforeach
```

What I want is to generate an empty input with its own delete button and same divs.

**Here are my 2 attempts.**

First with pure Javascript:

```
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button onclick="addInput(addrow);" type="button" id="addItem" class="btn btn-theme-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add item</button>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;

function addInput(divName) {

    var inputdiv = document.createElement('div');
    inputdiv.id = "item"+counter;
    inputdiv.className = "form-group col-sm-2";
    inputdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='myitems[]' class='form-control'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).append(inputdiv);

    var buttondiv= document.createElement('div');
    buttondiv.id = "button"+counter;
    buttondiv.className = "form-group col-sm-1" ;
    buttondiv.innerHTML =  "<button class='btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Löschen</button>";
    document.getElementById("item"+counter).append(buttondiv);

    var rowdiv = document.createElement('div');
    rowdiv.id ="row"+counter;
    rowdiv.className = "row";
    document.getElementById("button"+counter).append(rowdiv);

}
```

This creates divs within eachother which I obviously don't want. Also the new elements are added after the first not the last div.

**My second attempt with jQuery:**

```
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="button" id="addItem" class="btn btn-theme-outline btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add item</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addItem").click(function(){
        $("#addrow").append("<li>Appended item test</li>");
    });
});
```

This time I tried a li to test if it would be appended to the last child but instead it is appended to the first.

Any ideas how to append/delete the element in the @foreach every time I click on new item button on the last input?

Comment: Why is `<div class="row" id="addrow"></div>` in each foreach? Dont you only need one of those?

Comment: " I tried a li to test if it would be appended to the last child but instead it is appended to the first." how could you know since you append the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're duplicating `id='addrow'` for each iteration in your loop? You're going to have a bunch of duplicated id's. It's probably appending to the first `addrow` then breaking. I'd wrap your whole loop in a container, then append to that:

```
<div id="container">
    @foreach($items as $item)
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item[]" value="{{$item->name}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm" id="deleteitem">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                    </button>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addItem").click(function(){
        $("#container").append("<li>Appended item test</li>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="group">

@foreach($items as $item)
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item[]" value="{{$item->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
    <button class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm" id="deleteitem">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
    </button>
    </div>
@endforeach

</div> <!-- / #group -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addItem").click(function(){
        $("#group").append(template);
    });
});
```